# Why can I import a Cython module when working in one directory but not when working in another?

Tags: python-2.7, cython

I am making some tests to learn using `Cython`. I am using `pyximport` to import a `Cython` module into a `Python` script and I found the following problem:

If I execute the script while working in *one* directory, building the module *fails*. The error message says:

```
from . import Pipeline
```

> ImportError: Building module mymodule failed: ["ImportError: Building module _laplace failed: ['ImportError: cannot import name Pipeline\n']\n"]

On the contrary, if I copy my `Python` script and the `Cython` module in a *subfolder*, everything works fine.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Not with that litte information. Is there more to the error (copy-paste the full error trace). What is the organization? Is there a directory named `Pipeline` or a file named `Pipeline` with extension `.py`, `.pyc`, `.pyo`, `.so`, `.dll` or similar?

Comment: Hi @PierredeBuyl, 'Pipeline' is part of the Cython package, thus the error is not related to my code. I am working in a directory where I have both my '.py' script and the simple module '.pyx' that I am trying to import. I must be missing something obvious. I tried copying the same files into a subfolder and I successfully compiled the module and imported it in my script.

Comment: Usually, when the solution is to move the files it is related to the content of the directories. So, can you copy-paste the *full* error log (all lines) in your post and give the output of `ls` both in the non-working directory and the working directory? Also, does "python -m cython" work? (it should just output usage information).